# Is there a way to get the nearest places from a given list of locations in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

So, I wanted to implement a nearby feature using the flutter google maps API.

The thing is that **the nearby places would be shown from a provided list of locations** and **not the one used by GMaps**.

So say *I already have a list of places stored in a DB as coordinates*, **now say when I enter within 100m of any of those coordinates**, *I want to perform an action.*
Is it possible in Flutter using the Maps API?